# Kendo UI grid conditionally editable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to do conditionally editable cells in kendo by writing code:

```
   edit: function (e) {                         
      var kendoTextBox = e.container.find("input[name=Ordertype]")[0];
      if (kendoTextBox)
        kendoTextBox.enable(e.model.RequestAmount == 0);
    },
```

The ordertype column should be editable when RequestAmount column is 0, but is not. Can someone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the result of the code you have written?

Comment: Removed "thanks", explained that the expected result is not happening, and improved grammar. Needs a better explanation of what the result of the code is.

Comment: Sorry, the result of the written code is nothing, as before, without code :/ the console says nothing also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make cell readonly in Kendo Grid if condition is met](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881484/make-cell-readonly-in-kendo-grid-if-condition-is-met)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
edit: function (e) {
    var kendoTextBox = e.container.find("input[name=Ordertype]")[0];
    if (kendoTextBox && e.model.RequestAmount !== 0) 
        this.closeCell();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, doesnt work, grid works like before, no editable cells

Comment: @Dinone it works for me http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/UhiwI it doesnt let you edit the contact name when country is Germany

Comment: thank You very much, I didn't have cell edit option enabled, it works now! :)

Comment: do you know maybe what should I change if my inputs are dropdown lists and checkboxes?

Comment: @Dinone are you providing them as editors or in template directly??

Comment: I will have it tomorrow morning, thank You for help, I will posti it then if it is ok